What is the difference between "Detach" and "Extract" when converting a GitHub fork to a standalone repo?
I am going through the process of detaching a fork from an upstream repository, and I have been met with the following question:
GitHub support screenshot
I can't understand what the difference is between these two options. It reads like they do almost the same thing, just with different phrasing.
Can someone please explain what the unique features of each option are? I have attempted to find documentation on the difference between these two options, but have failed to find anything.
